# Optimizing MongoDB indexing (two fields query)

Tags: mongodb, indexing, spring-data-jpa, query-performance

I have two fields `scheduledStamp` and `email` in a mongodb collection called `inventory`.

Having the following jpa query:

```
fun findAllByScheduledStampAfterAndEmailEquals(scheduledStamp:Long,email:String):List<Inventory>
```

What is the best way to index this collection?

I want to have less indexes as possible, avoiding unnecessary indexes.

Knowing that:

- This collection can have more than million entries (index is needed)
- Querying by:

  ```
  db.inventory.find({ scheduledStamp: {$gt:1594048295294}})
  ```

  for sure results few entries
- Querying by:

  ```
  db.inventory.find({ email: "abc@gmail.com"})
  ```

  for sure results few entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support query only on email : Indexing email is must

If you need to support query only on scheduledStamp: Indexing scheduledStamp is must

If you want of query on both, a third index is required. But you can create a compound index to cover this query and one of the above queries.

Since Mongo follows prefix match for selecting index:

You may have index on {"email":1}  and {"scheduledStamp:1","email":1}

OR

You may have index on {"scheduledStamp":1}  and {"email:1","scheduledStamp":1}

But since you said these fields return few documents:
Just having 2 indexes on {"email":1} and {"scheduledStamp":1} may perform good if not optimum.

Comment: As I want to create few indexes as possible, using only index: {"scheduledStamp":1} Will perform good if I only want to query on both (scheduledStamp and email) ?

Comment: It can cover query on scheduledStamp as well as scheduledStamp,email but not just email